# docker containers for orderer and peer nodes for org1 and org2 are exiting before I can create a channel

Tags: docker, blockchain, hyperledger

When I using this command to bring up the network,
sudo ./network.sh up

This is the output.

```
`CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                               COMMAND             CREATED         STATUS                  PORTS                                                                                                                             NAMES
4334f4b87ae3   hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest     "/bin/bash"         1 second ago    Up Less than a second                                                                                                                                     cli
d687adcdf06f   hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"           2 seconds ago   Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp, :::7050->7050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp, :::7053->7053/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9443->9443/tcp, :::9443->9443/tcp   orderer.example.com
2a8c411263ea   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   2 seconds ago   Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp, :::9051->9051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9445->9445/tcp, :::9445->9445/tcp                                              peer0.org2.example.com
b74ad2f0dfef   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   2 seconds ago   Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, :::7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9444->9444/tcp, :::9444->9444/tcp                                              peer0.org1.example.com`
```

But as soon as I am trying to create a channel,
sudo ./network.sh createChannel -c channel1

This is my output.

```
Error: Post "https://localhost:7053/participation/v1/channels": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:7053: connect: connection refused

Channel creation failed
```

It is because when I tried to check with the following command,
sudo docker ps -a

This is my output.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                               COMMAND             CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
4334f4b87ae3   hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest     "/bin/bash"         43 seconds ago   Up 42 seconds                         cli
d687adcdf06f   hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"           44 seconds ago   Exited (1) 20 seconds ago             orderer.example.com
2a8c411263ea   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   44 seconds ago   Exited (1) 19 seconds ago             peer0.org2.example.com
b74ad2f0dfef   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   44 seconds ago   Exited (1) 19 seconds ago             peer0.org1.example.com
```

I have tried to reinstall docker and it worked after that but today (after 2 days), when I tried to create the channel again, I can see this error again. Its not possible to reinstall everything from scratch, please suggest a feasible solution or where I am going wrong.